# How can I use a global DateFormat-String with elements that interpret it differently? (JQuery datePicker, JSTL, Java)

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui, jsp, datepicker

I have a java web app, where one of the functionalities I need, is to fetch an existing date, and have the option of editing the date, by selecting another. This works really good with a JQuery DatePicker that I found, in combination with a regular input field, type text, that triggers the datepicker.

My existing date (GregorianCalendar) objects are loaded from a database, and parsed into JavaBeans, and further loaded into the jsp page, and the specific input field.

However, Java's SimpleDateFormat, JSTL functions-tag library, and DatePicker's [formatDate function](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate)! does not interpret formatting styles the same way. MM in java and JSTL gives "03", while in the DatePicker, it gives "March" as output. My desired "03" is achieved by the pattern mm in DatePicker, but then it shows the objects minutes, if any, in JSTL.

I figure there are two options. Either I create two patterns which can format the different outputs to the same desired String. Or I could use datePickers formatDate-function to format my java date object upon loading of the data.

I much desire to have only one global string pattern for my datepicker, because I want to be able to change the pattern without breaking the code, or having to many dependencies. Therefor solution number 2 is what I want.

Right now, this is my code for getting the formatted date String, using tag libraries:

```
<fmt:formatDate type="date" 
                pattern="${appdata.dateFormat}"               
                value="${myBeanObject.gregorianCalendarObject.time}">
</fmt:formatDate>
```

I want something like:

```
$.datepicker.formatDate( ${appdata.dateFormat},  
                         ${myBeanObject.gregorianCalendarObject.time});
```

However, with my limited JQuery/Javascript experience, I do not know how or where to put this code, and how to invoke the function correctly. Everything I seem to find about invoking scripts seem to involve an onclick, or "ready"-functions. I merely want to get the string, while building the page.

I realise that my problem is more basic than my title, but if anyone has another idea on how to get java's and the DatePicker's formatting patterns to play along, I would be happy to hear them. If not, how can I invoke the script, and get that String I want?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

So far I have added a small parser in my singleton applicationwide data object. When setting the dateFormat-string, it automatically parses the String to one that is matching JQuery DatePicker's mismatching interpretation. But to make this really work, I would need to add a whole lot of possible translations, other than month and year-patterns.

```
public void setDateFormat(String dateFormat) {
    this.dateFormat = dateFormat;
    datePickerFormat = dateFormat.replaceAll("yyyy", "yy");
    datePickerFormat = datePickerFormat.replaceAll("M", "m");
}
```

Comment: why not validate client-side in jquery, to input date in specific format only?

Comment: If you mean validating user input, that never applies directly. The users can not manually enter anything in the text field. What I wanted was a way for a single format pattern to be used across two different ways of interpreting. Upon loading of data from database, the string is formatted by JSTL tags, and put in a text field (input). but unless the pattern complies with that specified for the datepicker, the datepicker will not open on the correct date, when the user gives focus to the text field (which automatically opens the datepicker).